# whitespace nowrap in firefox

Tags: css, scroll, nowrap

I am using the custom scroll bar which has ul list inside. When evener the ul list or li content extends then the scroll bar is getting extended.

I have used white-space:nowrap for the main div so that ul width is getting extended but it is working only in chrome but not working in firefox/IE and other browsers.

Here is my code

```
<div class="horizontalaccordion">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading  2</h3>
                <div>
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 3.</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading 4</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 4</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 1.</div>
              </li>
                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 3.</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 2.</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>test</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel sow</div>
              </li>
                      <li>
                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 3.</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h3>Heading 4</h3>
                <div>Content For Panel 4</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.horizontalaccordion{
      height:auto; width:auto; white-space:nowrap; border-radius:4px !important; background-color: #b6b6b6; margin-right:15px ; height:95px; overflow:hidden      
}
.horizontalaccordion>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    list-style:none;
    height: 95px    ;  width:auto;   display:inline-block
}

.horizontalaccordion>ul>li {
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    list-style:none;
    width:38px;
    height: 95px; 

    /* CSS3 Transitions */
    transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.horizontalaccordion>ul>li>h3 {
    display:block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding:10px;
    height:65px;
    width:72px;
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px #616161; 

    /* Decorative CSS */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 95%, from(#BEBEBE), to(#B3B3B3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BEBEBE 0%, #B3B3B3 95%);
    font:bold 12px Myriad Pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#2c3e52;


    /* CSS3 Transform Rotate & Translate */
    white-space:nowrap;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3.0)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc);  /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3.0)"
                "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc)"; /* IE8 */
}

.horizontalaccordion>ul>li>div {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
    top:-88px;
    left:40px; 
    *top:0px;       /* IE7 Hack */
    *left:0px;      /* IE7 Hack */
    margin:0;
    width:auto;
    height:68px;
    padding:10px 50px 10px 10px; white-space:nowrap;
    background:#f0f0f0; color:#000;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #9b9b9b; box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #9b9b9b;
}
.horizontalaccordion>ul>li.hover {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}

.horizontalaccordion>ul>li.hover>div {
    display:block; 
}

horizontalaccordion>ul>li.hover>h3 {
    /* Decorative CSS */
    color:#fff;
    background:#000000;

    /* CSS3 Gradient Effect */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #454545, #000000); /* FF, Flock */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#454545), to(#000000)); /* Safari, Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.0)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff454545, endColorstr=#ff000000); /* IE 5.5 - IE 7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.0)"
                "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff454545, endColorstr=#ff000000)";   /* IE 8 */
}
.horizontalaccordion>ul>li>h3:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    /* Decorative CSS */

}

​
```

Answer (score 3):

[I set up your code on a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Gut/) to try and understand the issues a bit better.

A few things:

- Your HTML code is missing an opening `<li>` tag, which might be breaking things.
- For me the behaviour looks exactly the same on Firefox (14) and Chrome (18).  For the whitespace wrapping things you're asking about, even IE9 seems to be working.
- Without the accompanying Javascript, I'm not sure exactly how you want this to accordian to function.

The `white-space:nowrap` style rule is intended to prevent *text* from wrapping (See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)), (and it does this successfully in the Fiddle I linked to), but it does nothing to prevent elements from wrapping.

Perhaps what you want is to remove

```
whitespace: nowrap
```

and use one of these:

```
overflow-x: visible; /* shows all items even if the area is too small */
overflow-x: scroll; /* Will always show a scrollbar */
overflow-x: auto; /* Will only show a scrollbar when the content doesn't fit */
overflow-x: hidden; /* Content will just drop off the end of the page */
```

I hope this helps you.  It would be good if you could clarify exactly what it is you're hoping for.  On the JSFiddle you can change things around, update it and post a link if it will help us see exactly what it is you're looking for.